# Detect xml object type

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I've struggled for ages to implement a robust browser-independant means to load and navigate (using xpath) xml files within javascript; particularly where IE is concerned.

I've read with interest (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534370(v=vs.85).aspx - remarks paragraph which leads to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx) that IE started supporting **XMLHttpRequest** a while ago (IE8 or 9) but **.responseXML** still returned an **MSXML** object rather than a native XML object.  In IE10 it may or may not return a native XML object.

Furthermore, I've also found that if I happen to have an ActiveX version (where doc may or may not be an ActiveX object), then:

```
if(doc.selectNodes)
  return doc.selectNodes(....);
```

causes an exception on the if expression instead of just evaluating to falsey which is a pain in the a***.

As such (and here is my question!), it it true that even if IE returns a native XML object from **XHR.responseXML**, we still cannot use document.evaluate (or **xmlDoc.evaluate**) to perform xpath navigation?

I seem to have found that if I use XHR in IE and get a Native XML Document back I have no means at all to perform xpath (**.evaluate** doesn't work, neither does **.selectNodes**/ **.selectSingleNode**).  The result is, I am having to forcibly use **new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")** instead of XHR for all IE!

Any advice, would be great.  I can't believe I have to use **Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0** in IE if I want to use xpath!

Thanks.

Comment: This is still an issue for me although now that IE11 is out things are more complicated still as IE11 returns a native XML Document instead of a MSXML object from XHR.responseXML.  Any help would be appreciated.